# "string" in "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ServerVersion"

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, altv

Can someone help me I have updated all my nuget packages and now I get the following error:
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression state
Error CS1503 Argument '2': Unable to convert 'string' to 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ServerVersion'. Altv-Roleplay D:\Tookies-Development-main\altV Script-X\Altv-Roleplay\Altv-Roleplay\models\gtaContext.cs 101 Active

---

```
using AltV.Net.Data;
using AltV.Net;
using Altv_Roleplay.Utils;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Numerics;

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------



protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                //Local
                optionsBuilder.UseMySql($"server={Constants.DatabaseConfig.Host};port={Constants.DatabaseConfig.Port};user={Constants.DatabaseConfig.User};password={Constants.DatabaseConfig.Password};database={Constants .DatabaseConfig.Database}");
                optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql 6.0.0 and faced the same issue.
You just need to pass the server version and mySqlOptionsAction (nullable) as below

```
optionsBuilder.UseMySql("your connectionstring" , ServerVersion.AutoDetect(your connectionstring), null);
```